# UIO instance of a device-tree subnode

Tags: linux-kernel, io, device-tree

I have the following device-tree node which is auto generated by Xilinx PetaLinux in a proper dtsi file (which cannot be modified):

```
axi_dma_0: dma@a0000000 {
        #dma-cells = <1>;
        clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
        clocks = <&misc_clk_0>, <&misc_clk_0>, <&misc_clk_0>;
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-7.1", "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
        interrupt-names = "s2mm_introut";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 89 4>;
        reg = <0x0 0xa0000000 0x0 0x10000>;
        xlnx,addrwidth = <0x28>;
        xlnx,include-sg ;
        xlnx,sg-length-width = <0x1a>;
        dma-channel@a0000030 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0 89 4>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
        };
    }
```

To give access to the whole AXI DMA hardware from UIO, the following code can be used from another custom file that PetaLinux accounts for:

```
&axi_dma_0 {
    compatible = "generic-uio";
    linux,uio-name = "axi_dma";
};
```

What I would like to do is to give UIO access only to the `dma-channel` sub-node instead of the whole AXI DMA. To do this I tried something as this:

```
&axi_dma_0 {
    dma-channel@a0000030 {
        compatible = "generic-uio";
        linux,uio-name = "axi_dma_s2mm";
    };
};
```

Or adding `reg` space declaration to `dma-channel` subnode:

```
&axi_dma_0 {
    dma-channel@a0000030 {
        reg = <0x0 0xa0000030 0x0 0x28>;
        compatible = "generic-uio";
        linux,uio-name = "axi_dma_s2mm";
    };
};
```

Among others...
I cannot make it to create the `/dev/uioX` file..
What is wrong or what am I missing to make it work, or understand why it is not possible (if so) ?